# How do LED drivers with current control work

Tags: led, pwm, led-driver, constant-current

I'm reading the datasheets of this two LED drivers:

- [FL7760](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/fl7760-d.pdf)
- [STCS1A](http://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stcs1a.pdf)

The main obvious difference is the first driver requires an external MOSFET, while the second one has the transistor built-in.

But I'm focusing on the current regulation and dimming.
FL7760 is pretty clear about that. Figures 15 and following show how this work: when the driver is enabled (i.e. when the PWM input signal is high) the gate of the MOSFET is driven to keep the current that flows inside the LEDs (measured with the shunt resistor) at the desired value.

In this configuration, no matter the gap between the Vf of the LEDs and the Vin, there is no waste of power. Given that the MOSFET is correctly selected, there is no dissipation but the gate switching one. (I assume the Rds_on is very low).

But how does STCS1A works?
I cannot see in the datasheet a precise description.
Anyway, I mounted a sample circuits and I noted that the heat dissipation on the IC increase with the gap between Vf and Vin. For example, if the LED chain is close to the Vin voltage, the IC stay cool. With the same current, reducing the number of LEDs (that is, increase the gap between Vf and Vin) the IC gets more and more hot!

Questions:

1. how does the STCS1A current regulation work? And why does it dissipate more power when Vf << Vin?
2. is it correct to say FL7760 has a more efficient way to control the current? Or is there a drawback I cannot see?

Comment: The STCS1A is **quite different** as it is not **switching** (like the FL7760). It regulates the current using a pass resistor, similar to how linear voltage regulators work. For dimming the STCS1A you simply switch in on/off very fast using a PWM signal. Yes the FL7760 is more efficient but it is also **a completely different design**. You cannot simply compare the two. The STCS1A is a cheaper solution (no external transistor, no inductor), but the FL7760 can handle higher power.

Comment: Got it. The two goals I need to achieve in my design is to reduce the power dissipation on the driver (and here the FL7760 seems better) and avoid flickering at low duty-cycles. I'm not able to infer this from the datasheets. Anyway, STCS1A is very good even at DC < 5%. I hope FL7760 should be ok as well!